# Как получить файл (кириллица в имени) с FTP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, unicode

### Python 3.5, ftplib

В каком виде `ftp.nlst()` получает имена файлов? И как их привести к нормальному виду?

```
filelist = ftp.nlst()   - получаем список имен файлов
print (filelist[3])     - выводим имя 4-ого файла и получаем иероглифы
```

@jfs `>>> print(ascii(filelist[6])) '\xc8\xed\xf1\xf2\xf0\xf3\xea\xf6\xe8\xff.pdf'`

Спасибо за подробный ответ)

Comment: Чтобы исключить проблемы с отображением не-ASCII строк в вашем окружении, покажите `print(ascii(filelist[3]))`, чтобы помочь с отладкой. Что `ftp.encoding` показывает?

Comment: @jfs
>>> print(ascii(filelist[6]))
'\xc8\xed\xf1\xf2\xf0\xf3\xea\xf6\xe8\xff

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Python: Reading Ftp file list with UTF-8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523067/python-reading-ftp-file-list-with-utf-8)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523067/python-reading-ftp-file-list-with-utf-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Изначально (RFC 765, 959), FTP только 7-бит ASCII поддерживал, RFC 2640
расширяет поддержку до других кодировок,
[RFC 3659 уточняет](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659#section-2.2),
что команды такие как MLST могут вернуть пути либо в UTF-8 кодировке,
либо это может быть произвольная каша байтов—за некоторыми
исключениями такими как CRLF (новая строка, `b'\x0d\x0a'`), одинокий
Telnet IAC (`b'\xff'`).

На POSIX имена файлов могут быть произвольной последовательностью
байтов за исключением `b'\x2f'` и `b\x00'` (слэш и ноль).

В Питоне 3, `ftplib` формально использует latin-1 кодировку по
умолчанию, которая произвольную последовательность байт позволяет в
Unicode декодировать.

> **В:** В каком виде ftp.nlst() получает имена файлов?

`ftp.nlst()` возвращает список текстовых (Unicode) строк.

> **В:**  И как их привести к нормальному виду?

Если вы знаете, что сервер использует единственную кодировку для имён
файлов в вашем случае (вероятно, `utf-8`, если вывод команды `feat` её показывает) и нет
[непредставимых имён (PEP 383)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0383/),
то правильные имена можно получить декодированием:

```
filename = filename.encode(ftp.encoding).decode(your_encoding)
```

Можно передать `'surrogateescape'` обработчик ошибок в `.decode()`,
чтобы поддерживать и непредставимые имена (чтобы была возможность без
потерь восстановить изначальные байты, одновременно позволяя печатать представимые имена в «нормальном виде»).

---

Судя по результату `ascii()`, в вашем случае ftp-сервер возвращает имена в `cp1251` кодировке (ANSI codepage на русской Винде):

```
>>> print(ascii(filelist[6]))
'\xc8\xed\xf1\xf2\xf0\xf3\xea\xf6\xe8\xff'
```

В этом случае, `your_encoding='cp1251'`, чтобы получить исходное имя:

```
filename = filelist[6].encode(ftp.encoding).decode('cp1251')
# -> 'Инструкция'
```

Чтобы зря не перекодировать, можно перед вызовом `ftp.nlst()` выставить
`ftp.encoding = 'cp1251'`, если известно что все имена файлов в этой кодировке представимы. Тогда `ftp.nlst()` сразу вернёт правильно декодированные имена.